# English international driving license

Tags: uk-citizens, driving, taiwan

I’m living in Taiwan, need an English international driving license, which runs out yearly. I got this through the post office in the UK before I moved here. The only way to renew it is I have to go to the post office in person, back in the UK. This isn’t possible this year timing/money wise, so does anyone know of any other IDL for a Brit, that is accepted around the world, and can be applied for on line.....many thanks, Andy.

Comment: Why not get a Taiwanese one, since you reside in Taiwan?

Answer (score 3):

According to [uk.gov](https://www.gov.uk/driving-abroad), you can get an international driving permit (IDP) from the [post office](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/international-driving-permit), the [RAC](http://www.rac.co.uk/driving-abroad/international-driving-permit/), or the [AA](http://www.theaa.com/getaway/idp/).  The RAC and the AA apparently process applications through the mail, and the AA at least has explicit instructions for those who want their permits sent to overseas addresses.  However, to qualify for a British IDP, uk.gov notes that you must be a resident of Great Britain or Northern Ireland, so you may not in fact qualify.

In addition to the question of whether you qualify for an IDP issued in the UK,  you should consider whether Taiwanese law allows you to use your UK license if you reside in Taiwan.  Most jurisdictions have a time limit on residents using foreign driver's licenses; the longest such limit I know of is one year.